# DocuSign Merge Fields - Apex Toolkit

Tags: apex, docusign

I'm trying to see all the merge fields on a DocuSign template that I have hooked up to SalesForce. I've installed the Apex Toolkit, and gone through the TemplateService class to print out the custom fields.

```
for(dfsle.Template myTemplate : templates) {
    List<dfsle.CustomField> customFields = myTemplate.customFields;
    for(dfsle.CustomField customField : customFields) {
        System.debug(customField);
    }
}
```

But all I get in response is one custom field per Template with a name of 'templateUsageRestriction' and not all the other merge fields I've setup.

```
11:15:01.623 (1155694680)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|CustomField:[TYPE_LIST=list, TYPE_TEXT=text, isList=null, isText=null, items=(), name=templateUsageRestriction, required=false, show=false, type=text, value=allOptions]
```

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help you. Have you tried contacting DocuSign support? What did they say?